# Android studio + android annotations

Tags: java, android, аннотации

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь добавить в проект библиотеку `android annotations`, нашел [инструкцию](http://www.jayway.com/2014/02/21/androidannotations-setup-in-android-studio/), повторив которую, получаю ошибку, среда ругается на то, что нет дефолтной активити, которую нужно запустить.

И вот кое-что в скриншоте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно исправить?

[image]

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-apt'


apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName "simpls.podlinov.ru.reb"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "simpls.podlinov.ru.reb"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.0+"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.0+"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

общий gradle.build

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
}
```

проектный

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
....

def AAVersion = '3.1'
dependencies {

    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    ....
    apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.my.app'
        compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: кстати, стартовать надо с gradle команды.. например installApp..